# Woocommerce Product Gallery Lightbox and static main product image

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, lightbox

I'm a little bit stuck with woocommerce product gallery.

Is it possible to make main product image constant, and remove changing of this image by clicking other product gallery images? Instead of this, when clicking product gallery images - lightbox with clicked image appears.

thanks in advance!

Comment: What is you ultimate reason for wanting to do this?

Comment: Clients initiative, he thinks its very important to make static product image and other to open as gallery in lightbox

Comment: You'd probably need to code that up yourself, or you can check out my WooThumbs plugin: https://iconicwp.com/products/woothumbs/

It doesn't do exactly what you're asking for, but it does enhance the product image gallery.